# Implementing a common initialization for classes

Tags: php

I have 2 classes in their own individual files in a directory-

The first class:

**cat.php**

```
class Cat{

    protected $token;

    public function __construct($auth_token){
        $this->token = token;
    }

    public function showHeight(){}
```

The second class:

**dog.php**

```
class Dog{

    protected $token;

    public function __construct($auth_token){
        $this->token = token;
    }

    public function showWeight(){}
```

Now, I wish to have a sort of `common initialization` such that I have a central class that takes the `$auth_token` in the constructor and can call any of the methods in the classes.
E.g.

```
$client = new Client($auth_token);
$client->showWeight();
```

What's the most effective and efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Use class [inheritance](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php). Create a base class which the above classes [extends](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflection.extending.php).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I created a base class - `class MainClass {

    public function __construct($auth_token){ }
}`

And I did this for the dog class for example - `class Dog extends MainClass` and tried to call the showWeight() - using `$main = new MainClass($auth_token); $main->showWeight()` but I got an error - Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method App\MainClass::showWeight()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand you want a single class that inherits both classes. If so, you would have to create those two classes as traits so you can use them in a Single class as PHP doesn’t support multiple inheritance but by using Interfaces in PHP or using Traits in PHP instead of classes, we can implement it.

**Cat.php**

```
trait Cat{

    public function showHeight(){}
}
```

**Dog.php**

```
trait Dog{

    public function showWeight(){}
}
```

**Token.php**

```
class Token {
   protected $token;
    
   public function __construct($auth_token){
      $this->token = $auth_token;
   }
}
```

**Client.php**

```
class Client extends Token {
   use Cat, Dog;

   public function __construct($auth_token){
        parent::__construct($auth_token);
   }
}
```

And now you will be able to do this

```
$client = new Client($auth_token);
$client->showWeight();
```